# How to write inline styles for html tags in React?

Tags: reactjs, styling

I want to set a header tags styling froma top level component, something like this:

```
 <div style={{
        ['h2']: {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
    }}>
        <h2>test</h2>
    </div>
```

Where 'test' would have a red background, I can't do this any other way as in my use case I get a JSX Element as a variable that contains a h2 element, I cannot emphasise enough the top example with  is overly simplified and I cannot access the h2 tag in any obvious way in the real use case where I have to do something like {props.children}

Comment: Purpose of inline style is to apply the style to the element on which you are applying inline style. You can not apply style to other element using inline style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could even use styled components - this gives you more flexibility.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Div = styled.div`
 background-color: red
`;


const App = () => (
  <Div>
    <h2>Test</h2>
  </Div>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

it is only write inline style in tag style. you should use className like this:

```css
.content>h2{
   backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

```html
<div className="content">
  <h2>test</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, has to be inline style

Answer (score 1):

Use styled component and `h2` selector in style definition. So this gonna render a div which divs' h2 children gonna have red bg.

```js
const styled = styled.default; // = import styled from 'styled-components';

const Div = styled.div`
  h2 {background: red};
`;

const App = () => (
  <Div>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <p>Paragraph child is not redish</p>
  </Div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />,  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components@1.4.3/dist/styled-components.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use styled-components and create a component from a style component and update style on it like this :

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const H2 = styled.h2({
    fontSize: '1.5rem',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
});

const Test = () => {


    return (<><H2>Mon titre stylé</H2></>)
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thank you, explanation is now on the post

Answer (score 0):

You can also write inline style inside `helmet`. This requires you to install `react-helmet` and the result will be placed in the header of the html

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">

         <Helmet>
  
           {/* inline style elements */}
             <style type="text/css">{`
               body {
                background-color: blue;
               }
   
              p {
               font-size: 12px;
               }
              `}</style>
          </Helmet>

            <h2>test</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
```